# Unexpected behavior with .env in my ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I'm using node code as BE side.
using dotenv library for .env file. it works correctly but i encounter very weird behavior that i can't solve cause i can't see the root cause.

Also, my code is deployed into EC2 instance and the .env in the instance is include

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

in my constant.ts

```
const httpBE = `http://mySite:8000/`;
export const baseUrlBE = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? httpBE : http:localhost:8000`;
```

Also for explain the issue i open test route as follows:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();


app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
console.log(baseUrlBE,process.env.NODE_ENV) // http://localhost:8000 , production 
  res.send({ url: baseUrlBE, env: process.env.NODE_ENV });
});
```

Now , when i fetch this /test EP , I got that the env is read correctly but the baseUrl is not correct.

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8000",
  "env": "production"
}
```

also take look at the logs that cames out from the controller

```
console.log(baseUrlBE,process.env.NODE_ENV) 
=> http://localhost:8000 , production
```

what i'm missing?

Comment: This looks like an import order issue. When you access `NODE_ENV` in `constant.ts`, you're getting its value at the moment the file is imported. In your `/test` handler, you're accessing it at runtime. Check to make sure you're calling `dotEnv.config(...)` high enough in the tree before `constant.ts` is imported. You might even consider the CLI approach, something like: `node -r dotenv/config your_script.js`. More info on preloading: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#preload.

Comment: i really cant understand i call dotEnv.config(...) at the head of my main.ts . the wiered issue is if i log the baseUrlBE  and process.env.NODE_ENV it will log them as 
localhost and production . i really confusing. i edit this question with more details

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your project. I put together a sandbox to show you what I mean about import order: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sunset-g8v74g. It also depends on how you're bundling your files. Some bundlers will hoist imports, thus putting it above your `dotenv.config(...)` call even if it's the first line in the file. Did you try that `node -r dotenv/config` command I provided? It should resolve your issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hamilton-4qh45m (look in `package.json`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you have a typo, using colon instead of string. you wrote

```
export const baseUrlBE = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? httpBE : http:localhost:8000`
```

and it should be

```
export const baseUrlBE = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? httpBE `http:localhost:8000`;
```